# Under what circumstances can this happen?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

The a function $f = \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \in L_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is not in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but $\hat{f} \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Under what circumstances can this happen?

Comment: Are you asking only about functions such that  $f\notin L^1$, but $\widehat{f}\in L^1$ or do you also want $f\in L^2$?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: functions such that $f \in L_2$ and $f \notin L_1$, but $\hat{f} \in L_1$

Comment: Are you looking for counter-examples, or a general way to search for such counter examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually

The Fourier transformation is bijective only on $L_2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ not on $L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. So there is no contradiction to this.

Furthermore, because there is no inclusion between $L_1$ and $L_2$ these can happen without contradiction.

I hope it answers to your question.